# Using a raspberry pi to VPN into my home and perform apple Timemachine backups from anywhere

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, vpn, backup

I am considering a trip around the world and want to keep my data safe, no matter if i get robbed, lose my bags or other unknowns.

I use a macbook, and have a 8tb airport time capsule at home, which has 100mbit connectivity to the internet.

I would like to expose a vpn endpoint from a low power device such as a spare raspberry pi i have lying around, and allow access to a networked apple airport time capsule device which resides in my lan here.

Alternatively, i use an eero wifi router, and maybe? There is a way to expose a vpn or similar on it.

What setups would you recommend software wise to allow my macbook to perform backups via a vpn to the timecapsule?

Answer (score 1):

tbh, I'd look at something more robust. What happens if the Pi crashes, ISP changes your IP address & your dynamic access fails, etc?

As iCloud will have your 'vital' stuff, such as keychain & basically a way to get back into your 'life' in case of total loss of computer, then I'd be looking at something like Backblaze for the rest - accessible from anywhere, with guaranteed uptime & no VPN/firewalls to fight or prop open. You can pre-load it with a full backup before you leave, so it's only pushing incremental changes after that. You can then re-access it from any computer in the world, so long as you have the passwords [hence iCloud Keychain]. You're even covered if the house burns down whilst you're away. …and in these times of rapidly inflating power prices, wouldn't surprise me if it ends up costing less than your power bill for a localised solution.